# MySQL IF NULL of a variable is not working as expected in a trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger, variable

We have the following trigger to ensure that a version field is updated in a related table, normally the trigger contains only the UPDATE statement, the INSERTs are added for debugging and to explain the problem:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tableB_ins` BEFORE INSERT ON `tableB`
 FOR EACH ROW 
   BEGIN
     IF @`entityVersion` IS NOT NULL THEN

       INSERT INTO debug_log 
         VALUES (null, now(), "tableB_ins 1", NEW.taskId, IFNULL(@`entityVersion`, "WAS NULL"), ROW_COUNT());
       
       UPDATE tableA SET entityVersion = @`entityVersion` WHERE taskId = NEW.taskId;
       
       INSERT INTO debug_log 
         VALUES (null, now(), "tableB_ins 2", NEW.taskId, IFNULL(@`entityVersion`, "WAS NULL"), ROW_COUNT());

       SET @`entityVersion` := null;
     END IF;
   END ;;
```

The @entityVersion variable is set in a separate request before the INSERT into tableB, which is working as expected.
Sometimes we get the situation, that @entityVersion is not set and is therefore null. But randomly the above UPDATE and the debug INSERTs are still called, which should be prevented by the `IF @entityVersion IS NOT NULL` clause.

The content in the debug_log table is:

```
| 155 | 2022-10-11 12:39:18 | tableB_ins 1      | b613 | WAS NULL | -1           |
| 156 | 2022-10-11 12:39:18 | UPDATE WAS CALLED | b613 | 11       | 0            |
| 157 | 2022-10-11 12:39:18 | tableB_ins 2      | b613 | WAS NULL | 1            |
```

The final question: how can it be, that the inserts are added with "WAS NULL", which means that @entityVersion was null, although the IF NOT NULL is surround the statements?
How can that be?

Comment: *The @entityVersion variable is set in a separate request before the INSERT into tableB, which is working as expected. Sometimes we get the situation, that @entityVersion is not set* (#1) Does the variable SET statement and further INSERT are executed as one solid multiquery statement? (#2) If your INSERT statement inserts more than one row (or if you execute two INSERTs one-by-one w/o intermediate SET) then all trigger executions except the most first one will see NULL because of your final ```SET @`entityVersion` := null;``` statement.

Comment: @Akina: that entityVersion may be null is fine. The question is, why is entityVersion logged as null (the "was null" strings) into the debug_log table, although there is the `IF @`entityVersion` IS NOT NULL THEN` directly before.

Comment: *The content in the debug_log table is* Where the row with `UPDATE WAS CALLED` is taken from? There is no such INSERT in your trigger... does some another trigger which inserts this line was executed?